# Clip from orchestral classical instrumental

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

I've heard several times but don't know the name of it. It seems to be very famous.

https://clyp.it/r0sqwixf

Comment: I'm going with Bach or Beethoven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the "Badinerie" movement from J.S.Bach's Suite No. 2 in B minor, BWV 1067.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ufehp7gULA

Comment: In the original the melody is played by a flute, but in the example clip by an organ, I could not find a recording with an organ except one, which is more of a jazzy interpretation.

Comment: Good observation @guidot, I hadn't noticed that. The sound quality is quite bad, I just focused on identifying the melody.